# variables still update even if learning rate is set to 0

Tags: tensorflow

I train my model with tensorflow, after several iterations, the model output became  `Nan`. The I set the `lr=0` , I think the model weight will not update, however, after several iterations I still got `Nan`.  When I just load the data, print the output, totally cut the optimization process, I will not get `Nan`.

So I am quite curious why model still update when the `lr=0`.

I am using TF1.3. python2.7

I have tried `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` and  `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And your model will **not** update:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=42.)
cost_op = tf.square(w)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0).minimize(cost_op)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(10):
        _, cost, value = sess.run([train_op, cost_op, w])
        print(i, cost, value)
```

gives

```
(0, 1764.0, 42.0)
(1, 1764.0, 42.0)
(2, 1764.0, 42.0)
(3, 1764.0, 42.0)
(4, 1764.0, 42.0)
(5, 1764.0, 42.0)
(6, 1764.0, 42.0)
(7, 1764.0, 42.0)
(8, 1764.0, 42.0)
(9, 1764.0, 42.0)
```

for both `AdamOptimizer` and `GradientDescentOptimizer`. My best guess is a non-gradient update like BatchNorm and/or NaN in your data causing NaN. Or even a wrong operation.

How do you expect to get help without showing your implementation in a [mcve]?

Comment: The BatchNorm update also need a `lr`, and I am sure it is not due to my data because if I totally remove the `optimization` part, i.e. just print the output of the last model layer, it will not get `NaN` at any iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Patwiw is right!

In fact, it is because my code use `tf.log` to a **incorrect truth data**  which results in the `-inf` loss.